# How to get the total price from 2 tables (the quantity and price)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables. I need to get total cost of these 2 products but I can't. The question was: What is the total cost of Milk and Cheese from the shopping?

Table: Shopping

```
Product | Quantity
–-----------------
Dogfood | 1
Milk    | 2
Soup    | 5
Cheese  | 1
```

Table: Products

```
Product | Price
–--------------
Fish      123
Soup      657
Dogfood   210
Eggs      230
Cheese    120
Rhubarb   255
Milk      135
Banana    200
Apples    290
Lettuce    10
```

I am using this query on the terminal to get the total price of MILK and CHEESE, but when I run it, it doesn't return anything.

```
sqlite> SELECT Quantity*Price
...> FROM products INNER JOIN shopping
...> ON products.Product = shopping.Product
...> WHERE (products.Product = 'Cheese')AND (products.Product='Milk');
```

Comment: Update `AND` TO `OR`, `SUM(Quantity*Price)`

Answer (score 1):

Update `AND` TO `OR`, `SUM(Quantity*Price)`

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity*Price)
FROM products INNER JOIN shopping
ON products.Product = shopping.Product
WHERE (products.Product = 'Cheese') OR (products.Product='Milk');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Quantity*Price
FROM products INNER JOIN shopping
ON products.Product = shopping.Product
WHERE (products.Product = 'Cheese') **OR** (products.Product='Milk');
```

have you tried this?

Comment: I have tried that! But I need the total price of the 2 products. When I use OR, it displays the price of each items.

Comment: If you need total price then use sum(Quantity*price)